# Delphi Prism 2011 and Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, delphi, sharepoint, prism

can i create webparts controls for Sharepoint 2007 in Delphi Prism? If yes, how?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Sharepoint uses plain old ASP.NET WebParts. Even webparts that inherit from the Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart class ultimately inherit from ASP.NET's WebPart. You should have no problem creating a webpart for Sharepoint. Finding samples and tutorials is going to be a problem though, as 90% of Sharepoint development, samples and tools are in C#.

Comment: +1 The OP is on a hiding to nothing trying to do this. Even useing VB.NET is going to seriously limit the resources you will find to help you on your way.

Comment: Thanks, i've created an webpart but i don't know how to import it in sharepoint (on a new page it works).